# Using dart instead of JavaScript to manipulate the DOM, do you need a pubspec file?

Tags: html, dart

So with the standard HTML/CSS/JavaScript trio, you can write your html, import your .js file then get straight into a query selector and manipulate the DOM.

If I was to replace JavaScript with Dart in the trio, can I just import a .dart file, import dart:html then use a query selector, or do you have to ‘create a dart project’ and have a pubspec file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have a pubspec.yaml, you could just use the `dart2js` tool to transpile your dart code into javascript.

That being said there aren't many advantages in doing so, you still need a `pubspec.yaml` to use the imports that point to a `package:`, to be able to debug your dart code, and use tools such as `webdev` to serve/build your files.

Note: You'll always need to reference the generated javascript files (e.g. `main.dart.js`) in your html file, you cannot import the dart file without it being transpiled.

Comment: Thank you! Im interested using web tech that produces the most fastest efficient website, Ive read in many places that dart is significantly faster than JS, a more modern evolved language. 
But I still cant get my head around that how can it be faster if it gets transpiled into the thing that its supposed to be faster than? 
I feel like javascript would always be faster?